# Sympy simplify equation more

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, algebra

I have an expression in sympy like: `m*a+m*b+n*a+n*b`
Which could be simplified to `(a+b)*(m+n)`, but if I run `simplify()` on it I just get the same expression back. Is there any tricks to make it simplify more?

I have tried using `collect(expression, expression.free_symbols)` but that at best gets me only to `a⋅(m + n) + b⋅(m + n)`. I have thought about trying to run collect on combinations, but that would get out of hand very quickly since i have a lot more variables in my actual equation and also would have to look for subtractions and more. Is there any better way to do it?
Open to suggestions for other libraries also , not fixed on sympy.

Answer (score 2):

Use `factor` instead of `simplify`; the former is very specific in output while the latter is more general in trying to make the expression "nicer".

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.abc import a,b,m,n
>>> factor(m*a+m*b+n*a+n*b)
(a + b)*(m + n)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In some cases it helped, but in other cases of the equation is `m*a+m*b+n*a+n*b + c` and there it's unfortunately not working. Is there any way to deal with that?

Comment: Factoring is not unique, and factoring some terms separate from others (to get a "nicer" expression) is, in general, combinatorially hard. See [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19386) where the notion of collecting connected components works (and a routine that would work for your expression is given)...but has issues when all terms are connected.

Answer (score 0):

Getting too long for a comment on the [excellent `factor()` answer by **@smichr**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77968914/4541045), you can be more explicit about how you'd like it factored with [`collect()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/simplification.html#collect) if you already know approximately how you'd like the terms

```py
>>> collect(m*a+m*b+n*a+n*b, (m,n))
m*(a + b) + n*(a + b)
>>> collect(m*a+m*b+n*a+n*b+c, (m,n))
c + m*(a + b) + n*(a + b)
>>> collect(m*a+m*b+n*a+n*b+c, (a,c))
a*(m + n) + b*m + b*n + c
```